# How to get data from requests in python with a downloading link

Tags: python, python-requests, hyperlink, get-request

I want to get a file in my project using the requests module of python but the link that leads to that file starts downloading the file as it is clicked.

Like this one https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data

If I send a get request, it responds with the status

```
data = requests.get("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data")
print(data)
```

For this code the output is

```
<Response [200]>
```

But I want the file which is downloaded with link is clicked.

Is it possible to do so

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is raw, it includes response header and body, what you want is `data.content` (binary), there are also `data.text` for string and `data.json()` for json object

```
data = requests.get("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data")
# save to local storage
with open('iris.data', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data.content)
```